# Why is my cursor's notification URI getting nulled?

Tags: android

Our DocumentsProvider can't immediately service a query, so it returns a cursor with an EXTRA_LOADING flag and a notification URI (setNotificationUri).  Here's the [provider source](https://github.com/hahnjo/SMBProvider/blob/dev/src/de/hahnjo/android/smbprovider/provider/SMBProvider.java).  I think it's coded exactly as the [API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsProvider.html#queryChildDocuments%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String%29) suggest.

The caller is a separate app communicating through a content resolver ([caller source](http://zelea.com/project/overware/top/android/Precounter.java)).  It detects the flag, but receives a null value for the URI (getNotificationUri).  Why?

Hard-coding the URI on the caller side fixes it, but it won't port across providers.  What's a portable fix?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's an Android bug.  I opened a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182258).  Meantime I work around it by using the topmost URI of the provider as a default notification URI.  For example:

```
Uri qU = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree( tU, ... );
Cursor c = contentResolver.query( qU, ... );
boolean xL = c.getExtras().getBoolean( DocumentsContract.EXTRA_LOADING );
if( xL ) // then also expect notification URI
{
    Uri nU = c.getNotificationUri();
    boolean notifyForDescendents;
    if( nU == null ) //               <--- possible Android bug
    {
        // default to topmost ancestor of tU
        Uri.Builder b = new Uri.Builder();
        nU = b.scheme(tU.getScheme()).authority(tU.getAuthority()).build();
        notifyForDescendents = true;
    }
    else notifyForDescendents = false;
    contentResolver.registerContentObserver( nU, notifyForDescendents, ... );
}
```

This should port well across providers.